# Jison parser: Retrieve n number of text after a specific token

Tags: javascript, parsing, yacc, jison

I am using `jison parser` to parse my commands. I want to parse the command:

`grp <group_name> -i <id1> <id2> <id3> ......`

and want to retrieve the data as:

`{ group: <group_name>, id: [id1, id2, id3...] }`

But to parse using jison parser, I could try

`GROUP TEXT ID TEXT TEXT TEXT ...`
Here i will have to specify TEXT tokens 'n' number of times.

Can anyone tell me how to parse it without specifying n number of tokens?